# High Chart value is not coming on last bar

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I'm totally new to Highchart. Currently, I am facing an issue is that I'm not getting a label on the last bar of high chart[image: cha]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you high charts binding script
plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                        },
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                x: -10
                            }
                        }
                    }